# generic was used with wrong number of arguments error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, generics

Does anyone know what on earth this is? i can't get it to go away.

•model {"The generic type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`1' was used with the wrong number of generic arguments in assembly 'System.Web.Mvc...
it happens when i call a newly constructed model that i pass to a partial view, and try using/calling some methods of it in the view.

this is my userControl declaration:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of FP.AddFavAction)" %>
```

edit:

i see it in vs2010, but the code still runs yet it shows this error on breakpoint, yet it still runs and function as requested, but i still worry and want to know if i am doing something fundamentally wrong. googling this really returns almost nothing, but another question like mine that has gone totally unanswered!! there's got to be someone that knows whats going on, not one answer in the whole world. and have serched for the error message generically, removing the ViewUserControl`1 part, and of course teh assembly name!! wow!! –

Comment: do i need to make a "new" constructor for the addDavAction class?

Comment: could you provide full stack trace?

Comment: the code still runs but it has this error, how do i include the stack trace?

Comment: If you see the error message in your browser (YSOD) then the stack trace is below the error message. If you catch it with debugger in visual studio you have to click "show details". And if the error is shown only in the errors view in visual studio editor (compile time error) - then the stack trace is unavailable indeed. Where do you see the error?

Comment: i see it in vs2010, but the code still runs yet it shows this error on breakpoint, yet it still runs and function as requested, but i still worry and want to know if i am doing something fundamentally wrong. googling this really returns almost nothing, but another question like mine that has gone totally unanswered!! there's got to be someone that knows whats going on, not one answer in the whole world. and have serched for the error message generically, removing the ViewUserControl`1 part, and of course teh assembly name!! wow!!

Comment: Can you describe exactly WHERE you see this error? In the debugger watch window?

Comment: "it happens when i call a newly constructed model that i pass to a partial view, and try using/calling some methods of it in the view."

What exactly are you trying to say here??

Comment: Also if you post a question stick to it and try to follow responses of people that are trying to help you.

Comment: @jeroenh, yes, i see it in the debugger watch window
@mark, all im trying to say there is i call it normally, nothing exotic or weird, im just doing normal stuff as any mvc dev would, yet im getting this cryptic/strange error (once again, it still runs)

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I expected my model binder to pick up model values from the querystring,  but it won't. I set a breakpoint in the View, and then I'm trying to evaluate the ViewData property, it gives the subj exception. The stack trace is null, as well as the inner exception. The type of the exception is System.TypeLoadException.

Comment: there are so many bugs still prevelant in VS2010 that it aint even funny - combined with the fact that i don't believe MVC 2.0 is yet complete for real world development/scenarios, it all becomes really discouraging.

Comment: The StackTrace is Empty. I have the same problem for a String Property. "+ StringProperty {"The generic type 'GenericClass`1' was used with the wrong number of generic arguments in assembly 'WindowsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"GenericClass`1"} String". Renaming the Property did not help either. I found that using the actual string field worked instead of trying to access the property. Seems like a MS bug. Note I am using VS 2008

Comment: Thanks, just sent an email to scottgu as he will be able to forward this to the right department if in fact it is not by design.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl', however, I had a similar error when I attempted to pass a String Property to an unitialized DBCommand.CommandText. Perhaps your ViewUserControl is uninitialized.

**The error code:**

> "+ StringProperty {"The generic type
>   'GenericClass`1' was used with the
>   wrong number of generic arguments in
>   assembly 'WindowsApplication1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.":"GenericClass`1"}
>   String

**The original code:**

```
Using da As DbDataAdapter = DBFactory.CreateDataAdapter
     da.InsertCommand.CommandText = InsertCommand
     da.InsertCommand.Connection = conn
     da.Update(Me)
End Using
```

**The fix:**

```
Using da As DbDataAdapter = DBFactory.CreateDataAdapter
     da.InsertCommand = DBFactory.CreateCommand
     da.InsertCommand.CommandText = InsertCommand
     da.InsertCommand.Connection = conn
     da.Update(Me)
     da.InsertCommand.Dispose()
End Using
```

This might not be the exact problem, but the error code was very similar so I thought I'd share the solution to whomever comes across this thread. The Class I was working in was a Generic Class and thus the generic runtime error.

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing this, maybe brad Wilson, Phil haack or Scott Guthrie should take a look at it. Possible bug or undocumented breaking change somewhere in vs

Comment: I am not sure if its a bug. I think the error message properly reflects the the code. However, an improvement to the readability to the error message would be nice.